# One connection per user

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I know that this question was asked already, but it seems that some more things have to be clarified.  :)

Database is designed in the way that each user has proper privileges to read documents, so the connection pool needs to have a connection with different users, which is out of connection pool concept. Because of the optimization and the performance I need to call so-called "user preparation" which includes setting session variables, calculating and caching values in a cache, etc, and after then execute queries.

For now, I have two solutions. In the first solution, I first check that everything is prepared for the user and then execute one or more queries. In case it is not prepared then I need to call "user preparation", and then execute query or queries. With this solution, I lose a lot of performance because every time I have to do the checking and so I've decided for another solution.

The second solution includes "database pool" where each pool is for one user. Only at the first connection useCount === 0 (I do not use {direct: true}) I call "user preparation" (it is stored procedure that sets some session variables and prepares cache) and then execute sql queries.

User preparation I’ve done in the connect event within the initOptions parameter for initializing the pgPromise. I used the pg-promise-demo so I do not need to explain the rest of the code.

The code for pgp initialization with the wrapper of database pooling looks like this:

```
import * as promise from "bluebird";

import pgPromise from "pg-promise";

import { IDatabase, IMain, IOptions } from "pg-promise";
import { IExtensions, ProductsRepository, UsersRepository, Session, getUserFromJWT } from "../db/repos";
import { dbConfig } from "../server/config";

// pg-promise initialization options:
export const initOptions: IOptions<IExtensions> = {
  promiseLib: promise,

  async connect(client: any, dc: any, useCount: number) {
    if (useCount === 0) {
      try {
        await client.query(pgp.as.format("select prepareUser($1)", [getUserFromJWT(session.JWT)]));
      } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  },

  extend(obj: IExtensions, dc: any) {
    obj.users = new UsersRepository(obj);
    obj.products = new ProductsRepository(obj);
  }
};

type DB = IDatabase<IExtensions>&IExtensions;

const pgp: IMain = pgPromise(initOptions);

class DBPool {
  private pool = new Map();

  public get = (ct: any): DB => {
    const checkConfig = {...dbConfig, ...ct};
    const {host, port, database, user} = checkConfig;
    const dbKey = JSON.stringify({host, port, database, user})
    let db: DB = this.pool.get(dbKey) as DB;
    if (!db) {
      // const pgp: IMain = pgPromise(initOptions);
      db = pgp(checkConfig) as DB;
      this.pool.set(dbKey, db);
    }
    return db;
  }
}
export const dbPool = new DBPool();

import diagnostics = require("./diagnostics");
diagnostics.init(initOptions);
```

And web api looks like:

```
GET("/api/getuser/:id", (req: Request) => {
  const user = getUserFromJWT(session.JWT);
  const db = dbPool.get({ user });
  return db.users.findById(req.params.id);
});
```

I'm interested in whether the source code correctly instantiates pgp or should be instantiated within the if block inside get method (the line is  commented)?

I've seen that pg-promise uses DatabasePool singleton exported from dbPool.js which is similar to my DBPool class, but with the purpose of giving “WARNING: Creating a duplicate database object for the same connection”. Is it possible to use DatabasePool singleton instead of my dbPool singleton?

It seems to me that dbContext (the second parameter in pgp initialization) can solve my problem, but only if it could be forwarded as a function, not as a value or object. Am I wrong or can dbContext be dynamic when accessing a database object?

I wonder if there is a third (better) solution? Or any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are troubled by this warning:

> WARNING: Creating a duplicate database object for the same connection

but your intent is to maintain a separate pool per user, you can indicate so by providing any unique parameter for the connection. For example, you can include custom property with the user name:

```
const cn = {
    database: 'my-db',
    port: 12345,
    user: 'my-login-user',
    password: 'my-login-password'

    ....

    my_dynamic_user: 'john-doe'
}
```

This will be enough for the library to see that there is something unique in your connection, which doesn't match the other connections, and so it won't produce that warning.

This will work for connection strings as well.

---

Please note that what you are trying to achieve can only work well when the total number of connections well exceeds the number of users. For example, if you can use up to 100 connections, with up to 10 users. Then you can allocate 10 pools, each with up to 10 connections in it. Otherwise, scalability of your system will suffer, as total number of connections is a very limited resource, you would typically never go beyond 100 connections, as it creates excessive load on the CPU running so many physical connections concurrently. That's why sharing a single connection pool scales much better.